# Problem with embeding python code in html?

Tags: python, html

NOT SURE ABOUT THIS:
I think we cannot embed python code in html like we do with PHP, JSP

I have a piece of code I am trying to tamper with.

`PAGE = urllib.unquote_plus("%3C%21doctype+html+public+%22-%2F%2FW3C%2FDTD+HTML+4.01%2F%2FEN%22+%22http ........`

When I view source in the html file, I can see it being neatly displayed. But I am having a very hard time trying to figure out the %22 3C

What is happening? How to convert a sample code written neatly that python can understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template engine like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/), Django's Template Engine or [Mako Templates](http://www.makotemplates.org/).

Comment: I don't like embedding python code in html, but I think it's the best answer to the question ;-)

Comment: I need to add just one like like this
<img src="http://www..com/tw.png "/>

Do I need to use Django for this. Should I resort to decrypting the %3FC%2 etc ?

Is there any software which will automatically do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using <py-script> tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <!-- linking to PyScript assets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Put Python code inside the the <py-script> tag -->
    <py-script>
        print("Hello World!")
        input("Enter your name:")
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Learn more about this at the [PyScript site](https://pyscript.net/).